# Dismiss UIActivityView before completing the activity

Tags: ios, objective-c, facebook, uiactivity

I am using a custom `UIActivity` to share a picture on a **facebook** friends wall.

I am using a `customViewController` in order to display a `TableView` that lets the user pick the friend to which to share the photo, which I return from the overridden `activityViewController` method and I call `activityDidFinish` when the **facebook** operation has completed, which dismisses my `ViewController`.

**This works fine, but I want to :** 
Dismiss my `ViewController` after the user presses the button to post to facebook directly and then perform the task asynchronously in the background, so the user can do other stuff in the meantime.

Put more simply : 
Dismiss the custom `ViewController` visually before I call `activityDidFinish:`

So when I press the button I have :

```
[FBRequestConnection startWithGraphPath:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@/photos",uid] parameters:postVariablesDictionary HTTPMethod:@"POST" completionHandler:
 ^(FBRequestConnection *connection,
   id result,
   NSError *error)
 {
    if (!error)
    {
        [self activityDidFinish:YES];
    }
    else
    {
        [self activityDidFinish:NO];
    }
 }];
```

But I would already like to dismiss my `ViewController`visually before that, because in this case we actually have to see if the activity finished or not, for example in the default Facebook activity provided by Apple that posts to your own wall, the ModalViewController is dismissed immediately after you pressed the post button.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here's a working example:

[Example]
http://www.apeth.com/iOSBook/ch26.html#_activity_view

Notice that we end up by calling `activityDidFinish:`. That is what tears down the original interface. It may be that that is the step you are omitting. If not, just compare what you're doing with what I'm doing, since what I'm doing works (on iPhone).

Comment: Thanks for the input. But I feel that you didn't completely understand my problem. When the user clicks on the button "Post to a friends wall" the operation might take 2-3 seconds to complete, and that's when I can say that if it had an error or not and call activityDidFinish:YES or NO appropriately. In those 2-3 seconds the my custom ViewController is still showing; which is the part I don't want. Say in your example in the doDone: method you would have an operation that would be time consuming, you would want to dimiss the View directly and then return if it finished correctly or not ...